# WP-CLI doesn't regenerate media

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-cli

I am trying regenerate the all media via WP-CLI the command below:

```
wp media regenerate --yes
```

Unfortunately, it's return me the error:

```
No support for generating images found. Please install the Imagick or GD PHP extensions
```

Then I install the Imagick and GD extensions, but it's not help me. Have any ideas?

The output command `php -m`:

```
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
hash
iconv
imagick
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem it was the `hook` below:

```
function use_gd_editor($array): array
{
    return array('WP_Image_Editor_GD',);
}

add_filter('wp_image_editors', 'use_gd_editor');
```

I removed this code and it's work fine.